# Is there a way to allow only one instance of an existing win application?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to allow only one instance of any windows app? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [named mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). At the start of the application, typically the WinMain() function, if you succeed in having the mutex, it implies the instance is the first one else you can flag an error or activate the first application using other means.

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, "MY_MUTEX_123_UNIQUE_STRING");
if (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == GetLastError())
    std::cout<<"This is not the first instance\n";
else
    std::cout<<"This is first instance\n";
```

Comment: I *think* the question is about starting the same executable multiple times. I'm not sure and won't downvote, as the question is terribly imprecise.