# Denying linkage to a DLL from within the DLL itself

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, dll

I am attempting to develop a DLL that can only be linked once by a single program/thread and deny all attempts to link by other programs/threads after it has already been linked once. The state pertaining to whether the DLL is linked or not is stored and tracked via a Boolean variable but I cant figure out how to deny the linkage from within the DLL.

```
extern BOOL isReferenced; // To allow for only a single reference to the dll

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: // Linked to the library for the first time
        if (isReferenced != TRUE) {
            InitializeDll();
            isReferenced = TRUE;
        }
        else {
            // How does one deny access to the DLL?
        }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: // Linked to the library through a program thread
       break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH: // Unlinked from the library
       UninitializeDll();
       isReferenced = FALSE;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH: // Unlinked from the library through a program thread 
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to define "*deny linkage*" first. As a side note, `isReferenced` is a regular global variable, so (a) each process will have its own copy of it, and (b) it is not thread safe.

Comment: Did you try `return FALSE` in the line: `// How does one deny access to the DLL?`

Comment: Did you read the documentation on `DllMain`? What does it say about the return values for the different call reasons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to allow only one instance of an existing win application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563634/is-there-a-way-to-allow-only-one-instance-of-an-existing-win-application)